# height: 100% of overflowed content

Tags: css

Is it possible to make an element with `position: absolute;` have the full height of its parent, including overflowed content?

In the following code snippet the `.line` element gets cut off when scrolling the `.container`:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  width: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div style="height: 500px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: simply make the height very very big ... it's out of the flow so you won't have an issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks, but that makes the parent height also bigger

Comment: ah yes, the overflow will be considered ...

Comment: @Roope IE and Edge user already have a lot of broken stuffs, so they won't notice this :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding another wrapper can solve the issue:

```css
.container {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.container > div {
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  width: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div style="height: 500px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `height: 100%;` of the absolutely positioned element refers to the given CSS heigth (i.e. the height defined in the CSS rule) of the relative parent, not to its stretched "real height" when it overflows. So it will always have the initial parent height which is defined via CSS.

To achieve what you want, you'd have to get the parent height via javascript and apply it to the child.